# Ошибка TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, алгоритм

Всем привет, я перешел к изучению алгоритмов, но не понимаю почему ошибка, помогите пожалуйста, (python, binary search).

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Код:

```
   def binary_search(my_list, start, end, search):
   if start == end:
       return False
   else:
       mid = (start + end) // 2

   if search == my_list(mid):
       return mid

   elif search < my_list(mid):
       return binary_search(my_list, search, start, mid - 1)
   else:
       return binary_search(my_list, search, mid + 1, end)

my_list = [1, 3, 6, 9, 18, 36, 2, 5, 77, 111, 231, 142, 56, 34, 76, 89]

start = 0

end = len(my_list)

search = 9

options = binary_search(my_list, start, end, search)

if options == False:
   print(f'Number {search} is not on your list.')
else:
   print(f'Number {search} on your list has index {options}.')
```

Comment: `my_list(mid)` - нужны квадратные скобки вместо круглых. Вы же по индексу хотите адресоваться, а не функцию позвать (коей my_list не является).

Comment: похоже что позиции позиционных аргументов при вызове функции не соответствуют позициям при объявлении

Answer (score 1):

Обращение к элементу списка - с квадратными скобками

```
my_list[mid]
```

А поиск бинарный работать не будет, т.к. список не отсортирован